# Cannot access glassfish web admin console

Tags: glassfish, debian, glassfish-3

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/glassfish/installing-glassfish-311-on-ubuntu) with few changes to install GlassFish on a remote host.

- Debian 6.0.5 instead of Ubuntu 10.04
- GlassFish version 3.1.2.2 instead of 3.1.1
- sun-java6-jdk (1.6.0_26) - tested with openjdk 6u18 and 7u3 too.

Everything works fine, except the web admin console. I can deploy apps (e.g. Jenkins) via CLI and asadmin and they work. But i can not access the web admin console via http(s)://my-domain:4848

My Browser (Safari) notifies me about my self signed certificate and after a while it reports that it can't establish a secure connection to my server.

The log (glassfish/domains/domain1/log/server.log) is clean.
I turned off the firewall but the problem still exists.

Can someone help me to fix this Problem or have someone suggestions what i can try to fix it.

--

Thanks a lot,

Elmar

---

Edit: By disabling secure-admin, i can access the login page but can not login (*Secure Admin must be enabled to access the DAS remotely.*). With enalbed secure admin i can note even access the login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Safari. There is no problem to access the Admin-Console via Firefox.

Comment: I am having the same problem, all browser works but Safari, which is asking for my self signed certificate. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: My only solution is to use FF.

Comment: Check if you use a certificate with RSA algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

what does a "netstat -aptun | grep 4848" , tell ?

also see if secure admin is enabled ? "asadmin> get secure-admin.enabled"

As I know if secure-admin is disabled you are unable to access the DAS from remote .

I hope this will help.

Good luck.

Comment: netstat: tcp6       0      0 :::4848                 :::*                    LISTEN      3167/java

Comment: put here file domain.xml and make sure that server.log is clean , something should be logged

Answer (score 0):

Safari will not establish secure connection to a server with certificate that uses DSA Signature with SHA1 Digest signature algorithm. You will have to use RSA algorithm.

Try and create new certificate with this command:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keystore your_keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 1024
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the problem, because I created the certificate with RSA SHA1 signature. Further, other secured pages served by my glassfish working fine with safari.